# OS X 10.6+ key logging with time stamps for each key in any app

Tags: macos, logging, timestamp, key

I am currently putting together a workflow for a research lab. One of the components requires that we know the exact time at which any key is pressed in an application.

I've tried a couple of commercial keyloggers (Backtrack, Aobo) but they fail to timestamp each key press. Instead, they timestamp a series of key presses in the event that a program is opened or it's window activated.

Any ideas on how to record key presses with individual timestamps for each press?

Comment: You don't mention what language(s) you are using to develop this.  It sounds dangerously close to trying to write a general purpose keylogger though, which is probably something I'd rather avoid participating in.

Comment: I am not using a language to develop this. The software we are using (PsyScope) is designed to present stimuli as well as take input from the researcher while observing the subject. It is relevant to the study for us to know exactly when each input event (or key press) occurs from the researcher. Don't be too wary... there are legitimate needs for key-loggers too.

Comment: If you're not developing anything, this question is probably more suited to one of the other stack sites.

Comment: Will move my enquiry elsewhere. Thanks.